# String Trim Comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c++

I need to check whether the incoming string is not null and not empty

```
method(const char* utf8char){
```

....

```
string trim(char const *str){
    while(!isalnum(*str)) str++;
    end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    while(end > str && !isalnum(*end)) end--;
    return string(str, end+1);
}
```

**warning: comparison between pointer and integer**

Sorry for dumb question I am novice in C++.

Comment: Is there such thing as a null std::string?

Comment: I am getting  warning: comparison between pointer and integer
and connot compile

Comment: Please post minimal code that replicates the issue.

Comment: Consider posting your **complete code** (if you cannot reduce it to a minimal working sample). And also post the **full error message**.

Comment: I have not the full error message. because I am reading this from log file. Code without trim methiod is compiled but with it - not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works for me if the 'end' is declared as const char *:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

string trim(char const *str){
  while(!isalnum(*str)) str++;
  char const *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while(end > str && !isalnum(*end)) end--;
  return string(str, end+1);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  char buf[] = "  abc ";
  printf("%s", trim(buf).c_str()); // got "abc"
  return 0;
}
```

ps. vc10.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trio of functions I use that may be helpful:

The sch-parameter is a set of characters to be trimmed off.

```
void LTRIM(std::string& s, const char *sch)
{
    std::string ss=sch;
    int i=0, n=s.length();
    while ((i<n) && (ss.find(s.at(i),0)!=std::string::npos)) i++;
    s = (i>0)?s.substr(i,n-i):s;
}

void RTRIM(std::string& s, const char *sch)
{
    std::string ss=sch;
    int n = s.length()-1;
    int i=n;
    while ((i>0) && (ss.find( s.at(i),0)!=std::string::npos)) i--;
    s = (i<n)?s.substr(0,i+1):s;
}

void TRIM(std::string& s, const char *sch) { LTRIM(s, sch); RTRIM(s, sch); }
```